# Append a div inside a div and load the js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append a div inside a div and load a JS inside it. I actually want to do what [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/adamschwartz/rx6BQ/) is doing, but here the div is already predefined and on top of that JS and CSS files are getting applied to that div, but I need to append a div ad then act it as an odometer. How can I do it?

So here is what I'm trying.

```
<div id="abc" class="odometer">13</div>


$("#abc").append("<div id = 'odometer' class = 'odometer'><script src='http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/odometer.js'></script> <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-car.css' />")

abc.innerHTML = 222456.89;
```

I'm not getting the required o/p.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is written in documentation :

> How To Use.
>
> Add the js and a theme file to your page:
>
> Any element with class name "odometer" will automatically be made into an Odometer! When you want to >update the value, simply update it the same way you normally would.
>
> element.innerHTML = 123 // Native, or.
>   $('.odometer').html(123) // with jQuery

So, just create an HTML structure of your choice and add the .odometer class to the div in which you want to render the odometer it will automatically do that as these guys taking .odometer as a filter to find the source node.

You don't need to actually include the script inside the div include it anywhere inside body and you are good to go.

[Here is demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMISingh/vqQ9C/2/)

i have added borders for more clearity

```
.odometer {
    font-size: 100px;
    border: solid 4px green;
}
.outer {
    border: solid 4px red;
}
```

Comment: So this is how I'm doing. But its not happening. `$("#id_energy").append("<div id='odometer' class='odometer'></div>");
    odometer.innerHTML = (parseFloat(result)).toFixed(2);`

Comment: The issue with your approach is it was initializing automatically before even appending the node with .odometer class. Hence we need to create the object of this widget and then use it. check http://jsfiddle.net/AMISingh/vqQ9C/3/

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: Its almost near. Thanks, but When I'm passing decimal values it isnt taking it. I mean to say when I pass `102.3` it print it as `1023`.

Comment: It is because of the format property in the in the initializer object. just do format: '(,ddd).dd' as it tells how digit groups are formatted, and how many digits are shown after the decimal point take a look http://jsfiddle.net/AMISingh/vqQ9C/4/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40946/discussion-between-ami-and-praful-bagai)